# Counting number of regions in matrix

Tags: matrix, connectivity

I have the array:

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1
1 1 2 1
1 1 2 2
```

Assuming that the array has only 1s and 2s I want to count the regions of 2s. For the above example the answer is 2 regions.

My algorithm is the following:

```
I have another array of the same size holding boolean values, true for visited, false for un-visted.

1) Loop through the array
2) If is 1 and un-visted mark it as visited
3) If it is 2 and unvisited then I have to check cross-style the neighbours of this 2, that is Left, Right, Top, Bottom.
4) If in 3 the neighbour is 2 and unvisited then mark it as visited and continue the cross-style searching.
5) If at any given point, the left, right, top and bottom are seen it means that it is a region?
```

I am not sure if this algorithm will find all the possibles ways to count 2s regions and if this will work if with a simple loop I can move the cross-style shape to find the neighbours.

Can somebody give me a hint or if my logic is not in the right how can I make it work?

Comment: By saying region do you mean as long as they are one in four way connected then they belong to the same region?

Comment: I think you are right, but in general I mean the 4-neighbourhoods of a central pixel...

Answer (score 1):

Let `m` be a matrix of `n` rows and `m` columns. Here is the pseudo code of an algorithm that computes the desired number of regions inspired in the one described in the question. Note that I've used the collection of `unvisited` entries, rather than the collection of `visited` ones.

```
Let unvisited be the collection of all pairs (i, j); 1<=i<= n, 1<=j<=m.
Initialize the region counter := 0.
While unvisited is not empty do:
    Pick any unvisited pair (i, j).
    If matrix[i, j] = 2
      then
        counter := counter + 1
        visit(i, j)
      else remove (i, j) from unvisited.
Return counter
```

Where `visit(i, j)` is the recursive routine:

```
If unvisited contains (i, j) then
  Remove (i, j) from unvisited
  If matrix[i, j] = 2 then
    If j > 1 then visit(i, j - 1)
    If j < m then visit(i, j + 1)
    If i > 1 then visit(i - 1, j)
    If i < n then visit(i + 1, j)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What do you mean by unvisited as a collection of pairs? Is that a container?

Comment: That depends on the programming language you would use. For instance, you could initialize an array of n x m bits and use the convention that the pair (i, j) is in the "collection" if the bit at posiiton [i, j] is 1. Removing the element would then mean to clear that bit to 0.

Comment: It looks really interesting; I am not sure how I can randomise (?) the unvisited to have all the pairs (i,j).

Comment: The pseudo code would be on the lines of `unvisited := Array[n][m]`, and then `for i = 1 to n do {for j = 1 to m do {unvisited[i][j] := 1}}`.

Comment: I see I will try to code that and I will let you know. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, because count of searching will give you number of regions. Like in the following example:

```
    int region=0;

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            if(array[i][j]==1)
                ar[i][j]=true;
            else if(ar[i][j]==false){
                check(array,ar,4,i,j);
                region++;
            }
```

function check is for cross-searching, it bring two arrays and modifiy them. Its of course recursion function.

Comment: Thanks. Can you re-define what check function is? And this algorithm will work?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a mask. Then loop through each pixel. If it is not labeled, use it as a seed to find a connected component, such as all connected pixel label to 1. then label all pixels in the region. In the end, find biggest number in the mask.

Comment: Another matrix of the same dimension, basically mark every pixel 0 to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a generalised code to count the number of regions from a matrix that works with time complexity O(M*N)

```
rows, cols = 0, 0
def traverse_matrix(A, directions, i, j, visited):
    global rows, cols
    def isSafe(A, row, col, visited, current):
        return ( row >=0 and row < rows and col >=0 and col < cols and \
            not visited[row][col] and (current == A[row][col]))
    visited[i][j] = True
    #print i, j
    for k in range(len(directions)):
        if isSafe(A, i+directions[k][0], j+directions[k][1], visited, A[i][j]):
            traverse_matrix(A, directions, i+directions[k][0], j+directions[k][1], visited)

def solution(A):
    global rows, cols
    rows, cols = len(A), len(A[0])
    print A
    if(rows is 1 and cols is 1):
        return 1
    directions = [[1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0], [0, 1]]
    visited = []
    for i in range(rows):
        l = []
        for j in range(cols):
            l.append(False)
        visited.append(l)

    count = 0
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if not visited[i][j]:
                traverse_matrix(A, directions, i, j, visited)
                count += 1
    print "Regions count: {0}".format(count)

Output:
[[5, 4, 4], [4, 3, 4], [3, 2, 4], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4], [1, 4, 4], [4, 1, 1]]
Regions count: 11
[[2, 3, 3], [4, 4, 1], [2, 1, 1], [5, 2, 3], [5, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1]]
Regions count: 12
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Regions count: 9
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
Regions count: 3
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
Regions count: 3
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
Regions count: 2
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
Regions count: 4
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
Regions count: 1
```